# Laravel Page Expired 419

Tags: html, laravel, csrf

Some beginner Case:

I have an Upload Video Form from Drive, and when i upload a video from it, it takes a lot of times to upload the video. after finish uploaded, it return me an 419 expired.

so i assume the csrf_token has been change already when the video uploaded so the csrf doesnt match and return 419 (?)

i already do some test like:

- change App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken at protected $execpt and added my post link, the expired not comes out but it return a new problem with no post data sended.
- i have been thinking about refreshing the div {{csrf_token()}} every x second with jquery but i think it will give me another problem latter.

**This is my form**

```
<form method="POST" action="/video/insert" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="judul">Judul</label>
                    <input name="judul" type="text" class="form-control" id="judul" placeholder="Input judul">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="informasi">Informasi</label>
                    <input name="informasi" type="text" class="form-control" id="informasi" placeholder="Input informasi">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="link">Link</label>
                    <input name="link" type="file" class="form-control-file" id="link" placeholder="Input Link">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" hidden="">
                    <label for="status"></label>
                    <input name="status" type="text" class="form-control" id="status" placeholder="Input status" value="Tidak Aktif">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" hidden="">
                    <label for="outletstatus"></label>
                    <input name="outletstatus" type="text" class="form-control" id="outletstatus" placeholder="Input outletstatus" value="Tidak Aktif">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" hidden="">
                    <label for="type"></label>
                    <input name="type" type="text" class="form-control" id="type" placeholder="Input type" value="Server">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" hidden="">
                    <label for="user_id"></label>
                    <input name="user_id" type="text" class="form-control" id="user_id" placeholder="Input user_id" value="{{auth()->user()->id}}">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Web.php according to this issue

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth','checkRole:Admin,Pengguna']],function()
{   // Video Controller
    Route::post('/video/insert','VideoController@insert');
});
```

Controller:

```
public function insert(Request $request){
    $video = \App\Video::create($request->all());
    function getName($n) { 
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; 
        $randomString = ''; 

        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) { 
            $index = rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1); 
            $randomString .= $characters[$index]; 
        } 

        return $randomString; 
    } 

    if($request->type=='Server'){
        $videoName = getName(10) . $request->file('link')->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->file('link')->move('videos/',$videoName);
        $video->link = $videoName;     
    }
    else{
        $video->link = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$request->link;
    }
    $video->type = $request->type;
    $video->save();
    return redirect('video')->with('status','Video berhasil ditambahkan!');
}
```

my question is:

is there a chance we send the csrf token after the video is uploaded? so the csrf is not expired, and do you guys have some reference or some best way to do to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: update your controller code

Comment: Updated sir @MasoodKhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase your session lifetime in config/session.php

```
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Comment: Same issue sir i change the value to 1000

Comment: change the post_max value and timeout value in PHP configuration of your server.

Comment: man thanks so much, the configutration in my server was the problem!

Comment: No problem. Is it the timeout?packet_size?

Comment: max_execution_time at php-fpm is the issue haha. i feel so dumb

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that can be solution in addition of others that answered is to change

```
upload_max_filesize = 70M  post_max_size = 60M  memory_limit = 50M
```

in `php.ini` file.
And check `connection_timeout` setting in webserver too.

Comment: Thank you sir i will check that out also

Answer (score 0):

did you try wild card at protected $except variable with protocol

'http://www.example.com/video-uploader/*'

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: yap, i tried it already.
it gives me a new problem with no post data sended. i have a question also with that wildcard, is that giving us less security?

Comment: Its not if you upload it to third party api

Answer (score 0):

Check   if there is any other form is open before this close it.

Comment: yea there is a form before this form, i already delete the form (before) and try upload and still same issue :(

Comment: upload_max_filesize , post_max_size  in php.ini